# How do you toggle filtered list items inside of a div in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a React component that shows a filtered list of items in a div when users click on a button. Only the items within that div should be displayed on click. For some reason, though, the lists for *every* section are being toggled.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/6yr0jzlpwn

Comment: You only have one showWords variable, that all three buttons change and all three expansion lists share. So pressing any button will expand or contract all of the lists. I don't know react well enough to suggest a good solution for this sorry, e.g. one where you can use common code but it references a state flag on the button or on the div around the button.

Comment: That makes total sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can just define a specific value for each button then pass it to state

```
  <div>
    <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>

    <div>
      <button value={'1'} onClick={this.toggleWords}>肉</button>
      {this.state.showWords === '1' && (
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.filter(function(word) {
            return word[1] === "肉";
          }).map(function (word) {
            return <li>{word}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>

    <div>
      <button value={'2'} onClick={this.toggleWords}>茶</button>
    {this.state.showWords === '2' && (
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.filter(function(word) {
              return word[1] === "茶";
            }).map(function(word) {
              return <li>{word}</li>;
            })}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>

    <div>
      <button value={'3'} onClick={this.toggleWords}>日</button>
    {this.state.showWords === '3' && (
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.filter(function(word) {
            return word[0] === "日";
          }).map(function(word) {
            return <li>{word}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
```

In `toggleWords` function

```
toggleWords(e) {
    const clickedButton = e.target.value;
  if(clickedButton !== this.state.showWords){
      this.setState({ showWords: clickedButton })
    }else{
    this.setState({ showWords: '' }) // handle close list if double click
    }
  }
```

[image: Edit Practice | .map and .filter]

In case if you want to **expand two sections at once** you need to change `showWords` state to be an array then use `indexOf` method to extend the section

```
  <div>
    <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>

    <div>
      <button value={'1'} onClick={this.toggleWords}>肉</button>
      {this.state.showWords.indexOf('1') !== -1 && (
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.filter(function (word) {
            return word[1] === "肉";
          }).map(function (word) {
            return <li>{word}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>

    <div>
      <button value={'2'} onClick={this.toggleWords}>茶</button>
      {this.state.showWords.indexOf('2') !== -1 && (
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.filter(function (word) {
            return word[1] === "茶";
          }).map(function (word) {
            return <li>{word}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>

    <div>
      <button value={'3'} onClick={this.toggleWords}>日</button>
      {this.state.showWords.indexOf('3') !== -1 && (
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.filter(function (word) {
            return word[0] === "日";
          }).map(function (word) {
            return <li>{word}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then in `toggleWords` function will delete the value from array if exist else it will add it

```
  toggleWords(e) {
    const clickedButton = e.target.value;
    if (this.state.showWords.indexOf(clickedButton) !== -1) { // deleting the value from array if exist
      this.setState(prevState => ({ showWords: this.state.showWords.filter(d => d !== clickedButton) }))
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ showWords: [...prevState.showWords, clickedButton] }))
    }
  }
```

[image: Edit Practice | .map and .filter]

Comment: That's neat, but obviously it won't be possible to expand two sections at once. Which may be the required behaviour I suppose, but wasn't what I was expecting at least.

Comment: @Rup yes you are right I also forgot to handle close section if double click, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Liam Thanks for your detailed response! For this particular app, I only need to toggle one at a time, but it's useful knowing how to keep two open at once.

Comment: I'm glad to help.